# Visual Studio Code: Is there a way to build and debug in one step?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to build a target and debug that target all in one step in Visual Studio Code? This would be similar to the Build before running setup in Visual Studio. I'm running version 1.27.2 on Windows 7 and developing C code.

I already set a default item to build in my tasks.json file, and I have a default item configured in my debug settings.  I'm wondering if I can configure VS Code to do both items with one command, or a setting where I can configure my project to build before running/debugging.